2016 Honda Odyssey loses power on highway dashboard lights blink and then shuts down
2016 Honda Odyssey with 100,000 miles on it regularly serviced, lost power while driving on highway. Dash board lights blinked and then after getting to side of road shut down. Won’t start or anything. Push button start. If attempted to start dashboard lights blink, running lights at very dim.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked to see what the battery voltage reads?
